# Features differ between classes

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection, k-means, sparse

Good evening everyone.

Regarding the topic related to **Sparse Clustering** (for example K-Means).
For example, in "*Witten DM, Tibshirani R. A framework for feature selection in clustering*" the authors say

**"In Figure 2, we apply this method to a simple example with 6 equally-sized classes, where n = 120, p = 2000, and 200 features differ between classes"
What does it mean that 200 features differ between classes? How does this translate to R / Python / Matlab?**

**REF:**
*Witten DM, Tibshirani R. A framework for feature selection in clustering. J Am Stat Assoc. 2010 Jun 1; 105 (490): 713-726. doi: 10.1198 / jasa.2010.tm09415. PMID: 20811510; PMCID: PMC2930825.*

**LINK TO REF:**
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2930825/

Comment: It means that the distributions of 200 of these features are different depending on the class they belong to.

Comment: Mh, one thing I didn't understand. According to your reasoning, for example:
F1 belongs to A with N (x, 1)
Does F2 belong to B with N (x1,1) with x different from x1?
But there are 6 classes.
Or
F1 belongs to A, B, C, D, E, F with N (x, 1)
Does F2 belong to A, B, C, D, E, F, with N (x1,1) with x different from x1?
..
F200 belongs to A, B, C, D, E, F with N (x200,1)

F201 belongs to A, B, C, D, E, F with N (x201,1)
..
F2000 belongs to A, B, C, D, E, F with N (x2000,1) with x201 = x202 = .... = x2000?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I can't write it clearly and sorted.

Comment: Did you mean to write those in response to my answer?

Comment: I don't know how it works with comment replies, sorry.

However, I was referring to both.

Comment: I’ve edited to clarify.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In the case of the paper example, the first 200 features differ, for example, in the average.
But does each feature belong to a single class or does a feature belong to all classes but do the distributions between features change?

F1 -> A,B,C,D,E,F with N(x1,1)
F2 -> A,B,C,D,E,F with N(x2,1)
or F1 -> A, F2 -> B?

(My earlier comment may help you understand what I mean, but it's not neatly written)

Comment: Sorry, @dave.

In my example "n=120, p=2000, q=200", it means 120 obs per class (120*6), 2000 feature per class (2000*6)?

Comment: What are n, p, and q?

Comment: n=number of obs
p= number of feature
q = number of feature differ beetween classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that these features (jointly, not necessarily marginally) have some distribution for class A that differs from the distribution for class B.

It could be that the marginal means all differ between the classes.

It could be that the marginal variances differ between the classes.

It could be that one marginal mean is different and the difference is in variance for the rest of the features.

It could be that the marginal distributions are identical but the correlation between the features is different in class A than in class B (e.g., independent in class A but correlated in class B).

Let's give some examples, all of which I simulated in R.

First, we set up the simulation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
set.seed(2022)
N <- 1000
```

**NOW** let's simulate and plot three independent variables, two of which differ in means between the classes.

```
# Three variables, two of which differ in means between the classes
#
cA  <- rep("A", N)
cB  <- rep("B", N)
F1A <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F0 class A
F1B <- rnorm(N, 4, 1) # N(4, 1) on F0 class B
F2A <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F1 class A
F2B <- rnorm(N, 4, 1) # N(4, 1) on F1 class B
F3A <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F2 class A
F3B <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F2 class B
d <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c(cA, cB), 3),
  value = c(F1A, F1B, F2A, F2B, F3A, F3B),
  feature = rep(c("Feature_1", "Feature_2", "Feature_3"), rep(2*N, 3))
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(~feature) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**NEXT**, let's simulate and plot three independent variables, one of which differs in means between classes and one of which differs in variances.

[image]

**FINALLY**, let's simulate and plot three variables, all with equal margins between the classes but with a differnt correlation structure on features 1 and 2 between the classes.

```
# Three variables, all with equal margins between the 
# classes but with a differnt correlation structure 
# on features 1 and 2 between the classes
#
cA  <- rep("A", N)
cB  <- rep("B", N)
F_A <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.9, 0.9, 1), 2, 2))
F_B <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, -0.9, -0.9, 1), 2, 2))
#
# We have positive correlation in A and negative correlation in B,
# but the margins all are N(0, 1)
#
F1A <- F_A[, 1]
F1B <- F_B[, 1]
F2A <- F_A[, 2]
F2B <- F_B[, 2]
F3A <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F2 class A
F3B <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # N(0, 1) on F2 class B
d <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c(cA, cB), 3),
  value = c(F1A, F1B, F2A, F2B, F3A, F3B),
  feature = rep(c("Feature_1", "Feature_2", "Feature_3"), rep(2*N, 3))
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(~feature) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**THE** marginal distributions of all three features are the same! However, plotting the values of feature $1$ and feature $2$ in a scatterplot reveals there to be a difference.

```
dxy <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c(cA, cB), 2),
  Feature_1 = c(F1A, F1B),
  Feature_2 = c(F2A, F2B)
)
ggplot(dxy, aes(x = Feature_1, y = Feature_2, col = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**CLARIFICATION**

In my answer, $X$ has three components (features), $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, as in writing a regression like $y=x_1+x_2+x_3$. In the first two cases, $x_1$ has a different distribution for class $A$ than for class $B$, and ditto for $x_2$. In the final case, the marginal distributions are the same in classes $A$ and $B$, but the joint distribution of $(x_1,x_2)$ has positive correlation for class $A$, while the joint distribution of $(x_1,x_2)$ has negative correlation for class $B$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your kind and thorough reply.

Much of the data described in the papers talks about features that differ in averages, so your first example you have summaries described.

So, I understand, in the example case of my question, a pseudocode could be:

N <- 120
# Six classes are created as in your example (cA, .., cF)
# 2000 features are created, of which the first 200 differ (for example for the average) for each class (1,200) such as F1A, F1B, F2A, f2B
#The rest (201,2000) are created as F3A, F3B


then I can apply the K-Means and Sparse K-Means algorithm.