# How to check if two distribution with multiple variables are same?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

I have 10 datasets(csv) with 52 variables. Each dataset is an experiment.

I have 1 dataset(csv) with the same 52 variables in the control dataset.

What I am trying to prove is that:

1. All the 10 datasets are different from the control dataset. The problem is that some variables are hugely effected by the experiment. Some variables have no change at all.
2. Which variables have the highest change among the 52 variables in each experiment from the control dataset.

For #1, I have tried z-test, t-test. But isn't it focused on a single parameter of a distribution(i.e., one variable out of the 52). Can we say that a distribution is different of 1/52 variable is different?

Please provide some insights on how to achieve the above #1 and #2.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Some of what makes this interesting is that each of your individual variables could be the same across the experiments, yet the overall distribution could be different, as my example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584807/247274) describes. This means that it will be important to clarify what you want to learn from your data and why. (In particular, you know the data sets are different. Why test anything at all?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to study how an attack impacts a machine. So my control dataset is the stats of my machine before an attack and the experiments are when the attack occurs.